# Why Circular Content Carousel jQuery plugin does not work with Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I have been trying to add a jquery carousel to my website which is nearly completely based on  bootstrap 3. the problem is that the carousel which I added is not working. All the slides in the carousel are appearing at the same time and are overflowing onto other items in the website. I have attached all the necessary js and css files.

I have used [circular content carousel](http://tympanus.net/Development/CircularContentCarousel/)

Comment: Please post console errors (if they are), relevant jQuery and HTML. An [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/) example would help also

Comment: it has 3 js and 3css files. hard to make it into a fiddle.
html is like this :  http://jsfiddle.net/sveb8t7t/

Answer (score 1):

Circular content carousel uses [**`.live()`**](http://api.jquery.com/live/) as an event attachment, which is  deprecated since jQuery 1.7.

Bootstrap 3 requires jQuery in version 1.9 (or higher) which uses [**`.on()`**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for [**event delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) instead of `.live()`.

The problem is with these lines of the plugin code:

```
// click to open the item(s)
$el.find('a.ca-more').live('click.contentcarousel', function( event ) {
    //...
});

// click to close the item(s)
$el.find('a.ca-close').live('click.contentcarousel', function( event ) {
    //...
});
```

To get it work with boostrap 3 (jQuery >= 1.9) use `.on()` instead:

```
// click to open the item(s)
$el.find('a.ca-more').on('click.contentcarousel', function( event ) {
    //...
});

// click to close the item(s)
$el.find('a.ca-close').on('click.contentcarousel', function( event ) {
    //...
});
```