# jQuery conflicts using Content Carousel with Bootstrap 3 and Fancy Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, conflicting-libraries, circular-content-carousel

I am working on a site that is using the Circular Content Carousel from Tympanus in conjunction with FancyBox on a site built with Bootstrap 3. I've noticed however, that the collapsible mobile menu that is part of Bootstrap is not working on this page. I realized that Content Carousel is using jQuery 1.6.2 while Bootstrap uses 1.9 or higher. When I remove the link to jQuery-1.6.2 the mobile menu works but the Carousel breaks, and when I remove jQuery-1.11.1, the carousel works but the mobile menu is broken. Linking both results in the carousel working but the mobile menu not working. I've tried using the jQuery.conflict script to no avail (whoever built the site had already begun to implement this unsuccessfully).

I've tried changing lines 217 and 227 of the contentcarousel.js file from .live to .on as per the [stack overflow link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28924283/why-circular-content-carousel-jquery-plugin-does-not-work-with-bootstrap-3) and removing the older jquery file. Now everything almost works except when you click on the + sign to enter the lightbox and then exit out of the lightbox, the content carousel no longer works. I've also noticed that after this change, when you hover over the dropdown menu, it stays in an active 'mouseover' state.

The site is here http://smmcnyc.com/work/bnc/history.html with history2.html being the version with the modified contentcarousel.js file.

Suggestions? Advice? Please help!

Comment: This site immediately reminded me of "The Jinx." It's a jungle out there - be careful. Also, if you can put the relevant portion of your code / html into a snippet or [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: jfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/6m76o23y/